# AudioKit v5 - Why does the audio app crash in the simulator when I try to start the audio engine?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, audiokit

I am using AudioKit v5 to build a simple synth app. I start the app by setting up the UI and then preparing the various AudioKit objects, like oscillators.

However, when I try to start the engine with this code, the app crashes in the simulator:

```
1.        self.audio_engine.output = self.master_mixer
2.        try? self.audio_engine.start()
```

If I comment out the second line that attempts to start the engine, the app runs.

Does anyone know why the engine would crash? I will attach a screenshot of what Xcode jumps to when the app crashes.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

NOTE:
I can somewhat resolve the issue by removing two morphing oscillators from the master mixer. In this case, I would only be adding a sub oscillator and an fm oscillator to a mixer and then adding those to the master mixer.

Comment: Does the simulator crash or does your app crash? Does it work on a real iOS device?

Comment: @HangarRash, it runs on the device, but not without giving me this message in the console: "sp_oscmorph: size mismatch" 

...I am desperate to get it working with the simulators, though, so I can submit it to the App Store.

Comment: I can understand a desire to get it working for a simulator but what does that have to do with submitting it to Apple? If it works on a device, that is what matters. Lots of things don't work in the simulators that work on real devices.

Comment: @HangarRash, I think I heard (or read) somewhere that Apple runs all submitted apps on simulators during the app review process.

Comment: That's the first I've heard that in 15 years of developing iOS apps. Many things don't work the same on a simulator. Apple has to test on real devices to see how the app will really run on users' devices.

Comment: @HangarRash, that gives me hope. I might try to contact Apple Support and see if they recommend I continue without worrying about the simulator. I also just don't want to finish the app, only to realize I have to backtrack through more code than if I just try to debug now.